# Sql: How to connect tables by just using the ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

so I have this problem: I have 3 different tables that need to be connected to one another. It's rather complex and my english skills aren't that good. Let me show you:

```
        T1               T2              T3

  ID_T1 |Name |    |ID_T1|ID_T2|   |ID_T2|Spent|
      1 |James|    |    1|    4|   |   4 | 200 |
      2 |Mike |    |    2|    5|   |   5 | 300 |
      3 |Alex |    |    3|    6|   |   6 | 400 |
```

Basically I want to connect in Table `T3` the amount spent with the names in `T1` by using the ID I have in `T2`.

So I should "read" that James spent 200 dollars, Mike spent 300 and Alex 400.

Another thing to know is that the IDs are generated automatically, so I'm not supposed to be able to see them.

Do I have to pay attention on something when I create my Tables, or do I have to focus more on the `INSERT INTO` command (I work with Oracle sql Developer)?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Are ID_T1 and ID_T2 one-to-one mapped? If so, why do you need T2 table?

Comment: Also, Which database are you using exactly? (my guess is Oracle).

Comment: Also, do you need to insert every spending with a new ID_T2 in table T3?

Comment: There's nothing remotely complicated here

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an expected output.

```
Select a.Name, c.spend
From T1 a, T2 b, T3 c
Where a.Id_T1 = b.Id_T1
AND b.Id_T2 = c.Id_T2
```

Regarding your second question, you should know the relation between the tables meaning how they are connected.

Updating the answer as per your comments . Assuming that amount spend column you are going to hard code..

```
Select b.Id_T2 , "300" 
From T1 a ,T2 b
Where a.Id_T1 = b.Id_T1
```

But in above case , all the values for column spend would be 300.

Comment: Thank you for you help! This was very usefull. 
But let's assume, that I have to put informations in the T3 Table with the INSERT TO command, how should I proceed?

Comment: @Burkinaboy didn't get you. You want to insert data in T3 based on T1 and T2?

Comment: Jup that's correct! I have to insert the amount spent in T3 with the INSERT INTO comand. I could write 
INSERT INTO T3 (ID_T2, Spent) VALUES (............,'300'). 
But I don't know what I can write for ID_T2 so that the 300 dollars can be associated to Alex.

Answer (score 0):

@Burkinaboy might wanna try this

```
SELECT 
  T1.Name,
  T3.SPent
FROM T1 t0 RIGHT JOIN T2 t1 ON T1.ID_T1 = T2.ID_T1 RIGHT JOIN T3 t2 ON T3.ID_T2=T2.ID_T2
```

Comment: Thanks! But I didn't get those t0 and t1...? Do I have to put them in the code to?

Comment: the t0 and t1 are initials, you will need them in joining tables

Answer (score 0):

SELECT `T1`.`name`, `T3`.`spent` FROM `T1`, `T3` WHERE `T1`.`ID_T1`=`T2`.`ID_T1` AND `T2`.`ID_T2`=`T3`.`ID_T2`

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.name as name, t3.spent as spent
from t1
join t2 on t2.id_t1 = t1.id_t1
join t3 on t3.id_t2 = t2.id_t2
```

Use join instead of putting all tables in FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are inserting every spending in T3 table with a new ID, you can join the three tables and do a group by on it:

```
select
  T1.ID_T1 ID,
  T1.NAME,
  SUM(T3.SPENT) SPENT
from T1 inner join T2 on T1.ID_T1 = T2.ID_T1
inner join T3 on T2.ID_T2 = T3.ID_T2
GROUP BY T1.ID_T1, T1.NAME;
```

As of now, It's not clear which database you're using exactly. (I assumed that it's Oracle as you're using Oracle SQL Developer. Similar solution should be available in other DBMS as well in case it's not.).

First, Let's create the tables:

```
create table t1 (
  ID_T1 integer primary key,
  Name varchar2(100)
);

create table t2 (
  ID_T1 integer,
  ID_T2 integer,
  constraint pk primary key(ID_T1,ID_T2)
);

create table t3 (
  ID_T2 integer primary key,
  spent number(10,2)
);
```

Then create two sequences that'll be used while inserting:

```
create sequence t1_seq start with 1 increment by 1;
create sequence t2_seq start with 1 increment by 1;
```

Then a view which will display spendings per person:

```
create or replace view spendings
as
select
  T1.ID_T1 ID,
  T1.NAME,
  SUM(T3.SPENT) SPENT
from T1 inner join T2 on T1.ID_T1 = T2.ID_T1
inner join T3 on T2.ID_T2 = T3.ID_T2
GROUP BY T1.ID_T1, T1.NAME;
```

Then create an INSTEAD OF trigger on the above view to make the proper inserts in underlying tables:

```
create or replace trigger spendings_trig
instead of INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE on SPENDINGS
for each row
declare
  v_ID_T1 integer;
  v_ID_T2 integer;
  v_name t1.name%type;
begin
  if not inserting then
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Not supported');
  end if;

  begin
    if :new.ID is null then
      v_ID_T1 := T1_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
      insert into T1 (ID_T1, NAME) values (v_ID_T1, :new.NAME);
    end if;
    select ID_T1,NAME into v_ID_T1,v_name from T1
    where ID_T1 = :new.ID;

    if :new.name is not null and v_name <> :new.name then
      raise_application_error(-20002,'Incorrect name entered');
    end if;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      v_ID_T1 := :new.ID;
      insert into T1 (ID_T1, NAME) values (v_ID_T1, :new.NAME);
  end;

  v_ID_T2 := T2_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  insert into T2 values (v_ID_T1, v_ID_T2);
  insert into T3 values (v_ID_T2, :new.spent);
end;
/
```

Now if you insert into the view like this (assuming there is no data in any of the tables):

```
insert into spendings (name, spent) values ('James',100);
```

T1 will get a row

```
ID_T1  NAME
------------
1      James
```

T2 will get a row

```
ID_T1  ID_T2
------------
1      1
```

T3 will get a row

```
ID_T2  SPENT
-------------
1      100
```

Now if you do:

```
insert into spendings (id,spent) values (1,100);
```

T1 will not be inserted as there is already row present for ID = 1

T2 will get a row:

```
ID_T1  ID_T2
------------
1      1
1      2
```

T3 will get a row

```
ID_T2  SPENT
-------------
1      100
2      100
```

And

```
select * from spendings;
```

will show:

```
ID   NAME   SPENT
------------------
1    James  200
```